# Possible Infinite Loop when streaming response

Tags: c#, io, stream, infinite-loop

We are trying to identify high CPU usage in services we have, and we believe there are a few potential areas that may be causing infinite loops. Below is code that we believe may potentially be causing an infinite loop. Is there anything specific that sticks out that may cause the while loop to run indefinitely?

```
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(Url);
            request.ContentLength = formDataLength;
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Method = "POST";

            using (Stream rs = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                var postData = encoding.GetBytes(formData);
                rs.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);

                string str = string.Empty;
                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream sm = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        int totalBytesRead = 0;
                        long responseBytesToRead = 1024;
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[responseBytesToRead];
                        int bytesRead;
                        do
                        {
                            bytesRead = sm.Read(buffer, totalBytesRead, (int)(responseBytesToRead - totalBytesRead));
                            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                        } while (totalBytesRead < bytesRead);

                        request.Abort();
                        str = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
                    }
                }
                return str;
           }
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using the [WebClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)? Using it would shorten your code to 4-5 lines.

Answer (score 1):

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx) documentation:

> Return Value 
>   Type: System.Int32 The total number of bytes read into
>   the buffer. This can be less than the number of bytes requested if
>   that many bytes are not currently available, or zero (0) if the end of
>   the stream has been reached.

0 indicates the end of the stream.  The condition for reaching end of stream has already been defined.  The condition you rely on could be unreliable and is unnecessary.

Try

`while(bytesRead != 0)`

Comment: I agree that the condition is... weird, but it shouldn't be causing an infinite loop. `bytesRead` should still eventually be less than or equal to `totalBytesRead`.  I think something else is causing a lag.

Comment: @Cemafor - I agree, its difficult to say.  I would run this segment of code through a unit test to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use StreamReader

```
 using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
...
 reader.ReadToEnd();

// or

 while (!reader.EndOfStream)
 {
    // do read.
 }
```